# IE Edge rendering a button differently to every other browser I've tried (Chrome, Firefox and IE8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a website with a standard contact form. The button for this contact form is rendering inconsistently and I can't figure out why, I believe it is a rendering bug within IE Edge.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxzj2ma2/1/

```
<div class="col-xs-8 pull-both form-wrapper">
    <div class="col-xs-6 submit-wrapper">
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit your message</button>
    </div>
</div>

.col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.submit-wrapper {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
}
.submit {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 11px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Within Chrome, Firefox and even IE8 the button functions exactly as expected as displayed in the Jsfiddle linked above. The text within the button is centered and when the button is too small the word 'message' wraps beneath 'submit your'. 
Within IE Edge the button is notably off center from the minute it renders, it stays off center while resizing the button and when the text meets the edge of the button it overflows as seen on the third image below. Yes, it is possible to resolve the overflow with overflow: hidden; but that just masks the issue and you can't read all of the text.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyliV.jpg - On page load.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou7lu.jpg - 1080px screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSPSt.jpg - 720px screen.

This can be fixed within the IE developer tools by either disabling text-align: center;, adding float: left; or word-wrap: break-word; but that only works within the developer tools, any of these fixes applied within css do not fix the problem even with !important.

Is anyone able to confirm whether this is a rendering issue or if there is a fix?

Comment: This is a strange one